# EDMX canvas and generating a database from Model question

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edmx, edmx-designer

I generated the database from the model now I notice that all the tables have an "s" appended to then
Userid object transloated to Userids in SQL.

which nwhen I run the code

```
Userid userid = db.Userids.Find(id);
```

gives me this error:
**System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type Userid is not part of the model for the current context.'**

is the "s" added at the end of all the tables correct?

[image]

THIS IS THE ACTUAL ERROR I GET

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The entity type Userid is not part of the model for the current context.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

Comment: has been a long time, but I think its the olural setting of the generation But, it should judt work if you havnt changed it :/

Comment: Thanks Stefan! what is  olural setting of the generation

Comment: sorry... "Plural" settings. Its the thing which adds the additional `s`. I believe you can override it, so its worth to check it someting strange is going on. e.g.: pending database updates, a `[table("name")]` like override, something in the model creation parr etc

Comment: see https://edspencer.me.uk/posts/2012-03-13-entity-framework-plural-and-singular-table-names/